# Regarding license of plink/pscp/awk

Tags: awk, licensing, plink

My Windows application uses PLINK/PSCP and awk, and it just uses those binary out side of the Application. Just calling.
I see PLINK/PSCP is under MIT license, so no issue to use that, and no need to make my App public.
What about awk utility?
Is it Reciprocal license which should be opened in public?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. [[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)] for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one variation of awk which you might be using on Windows.  The most common are

- [gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) ([GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Copying)), e.g, from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm),
- [nawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/nawk.htm) (also known as BWK), and
- [mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/mawk.html) (GPLv2).

If you have only the executable, you can tell the difference between the two using their respective version options:

```
awk --version
```

for gawk, and

```
awk -Wversion
```

for mawk.  BWK provides no option for this.  Its license (you should read all of these, anyway) is close enough to PuTTY's MIT that you should have no issues with it.